# Grabbing value from a key from a response string from httpclient

Tags: c#, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to grab a value from a post request using `System.Net.Http`. The keys are returned in a string representation of a dictionary.

My response string looks something like this, a string representation of a dictionary:

```
"{\"primaryKey\": \"hereIsMyKeyValue\",\"secondaryKey\":\"jsfidjsi\"}"
```

**Relevant code**

This is what I am doing right now to make the post request and reading my response

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**What I've tried**

I tried using `.Trim()` to get rid of the escape characters `\`. but that does nothing.

```
   var test = responseString.Trim();
```

How can I grab the contents of either of those keys that's in the string representation? Or am I approaching the problem by trying to manipulate what is returned from `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` ?

Comment: Something doesn't look quite right here. Is the response you've shown the actual content, or is it what shows up in the VS debug view? If it's the debug view, an attempt to trim backslashes will do nothing because they really aren't in the string - it's an artifact of the debugger - it is escaping characters for clarity(?)

Comment: @Zenilogix yes the response is what I get from looking in the debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a few assumptions about what you are attempting,

You probably want to use something like NewtonSoft to deserialize the Json:

```
class MyDictionaryItem
{
    [JsonProperty("primaryKey")]
    public string PrimaryKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("secondaryKey")]
    public string SecondaryKey { get; set; }
}

var myResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDictionaryItem>(responseString);
```

You can then access the value you want as a member of `myResult`.